# Scroll View not scrolling when using Embed In

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scrollview

I have items inside a view that I want to be scrollable.  I did the following:

- Selected all items in my view "DesignalbleView"
- Went to Editor -> Embed in -> Scroll View
- Added constraints on the scroll view to 0 on all sides

[image]

[image]

If I test in the simulator it does not scroll.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you add constraints from the embedded views to the scroll view's Content Layout Guide?

Comment: Follow this tutorial: https://medium.com/@luisfmachado/uiscrollview-autolayout-on-a-storyboard-a-step-by-step-guide-15bd67ee79e9

Comment: @DonMag I updated the question with a screenshot of the constraints. All set to 0 and the only option is DesiableView which is the parent.

Comment: @albertski - that doesn't show anything related to your constraints *inside* the scroll view. You have to tell the scroll view what the "scrollable area" should be. The best way to do that is by constraining the scroll view's subviews to the scroll view's Content Layout Guide